# Angular proper models with validation

Tags: angularjs, model

What's the best approach to build proper models in Angular?

Angular is missing Models that can:

1. Can be used by multiple controllers
2. Contain validation that is reflected in the view and
3. Can sync to a backend (CRUD)

We can handle the first limitation using Service or Factory as a model and inject it into one or more controllers. This works well to separate data from controller. The $scope is also bound to the model properly, updating both ways. However this doesn't give us a way to specify validation rules in the model that could be relayed to one or many views using the model.

Angular has support for validation but only at the view level. This results in validation rules being duplicated between views using the same model and the model itself. After all, we need to validate the data at the model level, not just the UI. Moreover, the backend model also needs to validate the data coming in (you can't let a simple curl command corrupt your server). Ideally we'd want a mechanism to specify validation/schema at the backend and client (Angular) level but that's beyond the scope of my question. I'd be happy with having to specify validation only at the model which would then communicate it to the views.

Another limitation of models in Angular (or rather not having models) is that we end up having to create all of the automatic CRUD functionality to the backend manually, typically using ngResource.

I've seen some partial solutions to these problems online but they are typically short lived or limited scope project. The best one is probably this one
https://github.com/FacultyCreative/ngActiveResource
It was created by the author for a series of tutorials. It basically tries to recreate the Rails ActiveRecord ORM. Unfortunately this repo has had no activity since April.

Am I missing something and is this something that's on the table for an upcoming version of Angular?

Comment: There is client-side validation and then there is server-side validation. They are separate and should not be considered 'duplicated' effort.  With server-side validation, you could return a model that contains the status of the post (success/error) as well as an array of validation rules that were broken. These rules can be rendered any way you like.

Comment: Angular is purely client-side. I'm asking about client-side models mostly here, although yes these client-side models need to talk to server-side services/models with their own validation. The validation of both needs to be duplicated since not every request to the server side model can be assumed to originate from the client-side model. One could use 'curl' to issue a post for instance.